# What's the non-log form of this equation?

Tags: logarithms

I found this equation in a book and I'd like to know what it would look like in 'non-log' form:

$(a \log x + b \log N)^2 + 2g \log x + 2f \log N + C = 0$

Thanks.

Comment: You can substitute: $\log(N)=u$  and $\log(x)=v$

Comment: What's exactly the form you request? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi, in other words, I want to know what the equation is like when you apply the exp function in both sides.

Comment: If you do what @calculus suggested, you just face a quadratic equation in $u$ or $v$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, Claude and @calculus